# prompted for password too often

Tags: database, civicrm-home, settings, civicrm.settings.php

I am trying to run civicrm in my machine and access it through LAN from other machines. So I made a change in word press general settings like below:

WordPress Address (URL)  http://myipaddress/mysite
Site Address (URL)  http://myipaddress/mysite

After this, whenver I am doing a search/report/ any function in civicrm I am being prompted for password. And after that I am directed to civicrm home page and the loop repeats. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changed the base URL in civicrm.settings.php . now works fine .

if (!defined('CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 'http://localhost/site/'); 
}

is changed to

if (!defined('CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 'http://myipaddress/site');
}

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to your own question.  Could you provide a bit more detail to help anyone else who has the same problem?

Comment: Edited the answer William. let me know if that is ok

Comment: Yes, that's much clearer. Thanks! You could also mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the tick beside this answer.

Comment: will do that tomorrow. not allowing today to do it